# Street number doesn't change in CiviCRM after filling out Drupal Form

Tags: drupal, forms

Street number doesn't change in CiviCRM after filling out Drupal Form, which is connected to CiviCRM. The correct street name is collected in the Drupal results, in the confirmation e-mail and in the activity. The problem is, it is not changed automatically in CiviCRM even though the field in the Drupal Form is directly linked to that field in CiviCRM.

Comment: have you turned on Address Parsing or something that is giving you those as separate fields. standard civi would not give you both fields as separate iirc.

Comment: Yes we did. Still working on this problem. We use three fields in the form:
1. Street name
2. Street number
3. Street number Suffix

Comment: Do you actually need to be parsing the address? most users of civi do not use that feature